# How to programmatically setObjectClass for NSArrayController

Tags: cocoa, nsarraycontroller

I'm having a problem with what should be a very simple thing.  I want to create an NSArrayController and specify the class it manages.  Problem is, I can't figure out the correct way to specify the Class in the setObjectClass method.  I want to do the following:

```
[projectArrayController setObjectClass:SKHProject];
```

SKHProject is a class that I've imported in the implementation file.  I keep getting the "Expected expression before 'SKHProject'" error, but I can't figure out the correct expression. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
[projectArrayController setObjectClass:[SKHProject class]];
```

!

Answer (score 0):

Just found it

```
[projectArrayController setObjectClass:[SKHProject class]];
```

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can only use a class name as the receiver of a message; you can't use it in any other context. So, to pass the `Class` somewhere, send it a message asking it for itself: `[SKHProjectClass class]`.